# XML serialisation and deserialisation in another remote type

Tags: c#, xml, webclient

I need to call a webmethod using WebClient (without adding a reference).
The web method takes an array of departments as parameter.

```
public class Departement 
{
    [XmlElement (Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    string Id;
    [XmlElement (Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    List<Student> listStident = new List<Student> ();
}
public class Student 
{
    [XmlElement (Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    string firstName;
    [XmlElement (Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    string lastName;
}
```

I have the same class in my project. So the idea is to serialize my array and deserialise it in the type of the remote class, so i can pass it as parameter.
But when i deserialize, the new object contains the values for simple type properties, but not the complex ones.

```
Id = 110;
listStident = null;
```

This is my code;

```
public Object Deserialize(xmlDocument xmlDocument, Type type)
{
    object result = new object();
    var serializer = new Xmlserializer(type);
    if(type.IsArray)
        result = Activator.CreateInstance(type, xmlDocument.FirstChild.NextSibling.ChildNodes.Count)
    else
        result = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    using(XmlReader xmlReader = new xmlNodeReader(xmlDocument)) 
    {
        result = Convert.ChangeType(serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader), type);
    }     
    return result;           
}
```

The Type type is the type of the parameter of the WebMethod from the dyanamicly loaded assembly.

```
Type type = myRemoteWebMethod.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType;
```

Comment: what do you mean "without adding a reference"?

Comment: probably you haven't specified the namespace on the other classes you are deserializing to.

Comment: @MatthewEvans withou adding a web reference. the assembly is loaded dynamicly

Comment: @csharpwinphonexaml how can i do that?

Comment: What I mean is that if the type that you have where you are calling the webclient and where you are trying to deserialize doesn't have the same [XmlElement(namespace=...)] attributes it will not be able to deserialize

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Here is the code :

```
public class Departement {
     [XmlElement (Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
     string Id;
     [XmlArray("Students", Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
     [XmlArrayItem("Student")]
     List<Student> listStident = new List<Student> ();
 }
```

It works.